# Is this considered a passive voice misuse?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

"She was sleeping while the boy was tasked to clean up the house."

I came up with this sentence, it sounds right for me, but Grammarly keeps telling me that it's a passive voice misuse. How can I fix this?

Comment: Grammarly and other so-called grammar checkers should be used strictly for that purpose: to signal you to double-check that you wrote what you intended to say. They are not authorities on the language. Passive voice serves a role in the language (hence, for example, its existence) and is not inherently a "misuse" to be "fixed" if used correctly.

Comment: I'd normally consider 'task' as being nearer the punctive extreme. _Assign a task_. Try "She was sleeping when the boy was tasked to clean up the house."

Answer (score 6):

Do not slavishly follow the advice of grammar checkers. Even better, do not use them at all. There is nothing wrong with the occasional use of the passive voice.

Comment: Good advice. Yet, there is the usual pairing of *tasked with* rather than *tasked to*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Indeed. One might also suggest _when_ rather than _while_, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Agreed! There are many cases where you want to avoid saying who initiated the action! "The computer's hard drive was accidentally formatted." vs "Bob accidentally formatted the computer's hard drive." It was an accident, so no need to tell the world it was Bob who did it! We don't want people to think worse of Bob because of an accident.

Comment: She was sleeping. The boy was tasked to clean the house. -- I have utterly no idea what the first thought has to do with the second. Since the second phrase is passive voice, it is not even clear if "she" made the boy clean while she slept, or some other actor is compelling the boy.

Comment: The answer 'Do not slavishly follow Grammarly's advice [when 'passive voice misuse' is flagged]' has been given before.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Very likely, and possibly by me (as well as others).

Comment: Don't you think that repeat answers are as counter to the ELU ethos as repeat questions (which we are encouraged to CV)? I've downvoted this repeated answer, but am considering mod-flagging.